# Запутался с указателями с++

Tags: c, указатели

Я преобразовал некую функцию так что она принимала указатель на переменную типа `a_t`, а теперь принимает указатель на массив указателей типа `a_t`

Было:

```
a_t * cell
```

Стало:

```
a_t * cells
```

В функции вызывалось:

```
cell->payload
```

Мне же нужно вызвать то же самое от первого элемента массива, я поменял эту строку на:

```
((*cells)[0])->payload
```

но оно выделяет ошибку и я не понимаю в чем причина

ошибка:

> expression must have pointer-to-object typeC/C++(142)

Работаю в vs code

Comment: `*cells` - это `a_t`, что такое `a_t[0]` и тем более `a_t[0]->payload`?

Comment: payload - переменная из структуры a_t

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Я преобразовал некую функцию так что она принимала указатель на
> переменную типа a_t

```
a_t* cell
```

ок, корректно

> а теперь принимает указатель на массив указателей типа a_t

```
a_t * cells
```

а вот это очень странно, должно быть так:

```
a_t** cells
```

и тогда

`cells[0]` - это указатель на `a_t` и можно делать

```
cells[0]->payload
```

если `payload` - это `a_t::payload`